# Arduino and motor driver l298n separate power supply circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, driver

I have an inquiry regarding the l298n motor driver.

I encountered a problem while using it. It's like this: every time i attach the wires of my dc motors into the board's "motor A" and "motor B" connectors, my dc motors wont move. I re-checked my code to see if there were errors, but there were no errors both in syntax and in logic.

I also noticed, that when i test the voltages at the connectors, there is no voltage output. But every time i remove my dc motors from the connectors and test the voltages at the connectors, there is voltage output. I am confused and i dont really know how to solve this problem. I've searched as much as possibly could in the net, but to no avail.

I am hoping you guys could help me. i would really appreciate it.

Below is a diagram of my circuit. As you can see i plan to power the arduino and motor driver separately, since i am using bigger motors.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a connection from arduino ground to the driver board ground and supply 5v from arduino board to driver's board 5v input.

Comment: i would like to ask for clarification... most of the sources in the net say that the +5v connector on the l298n board acts as output, is possible for it to be as input without causing any problems?

Comment: hehe, your first response actually solved my problem. it was just now that i actually implemented your suggestion and it works!

got my device up and running 100% :).

thanks for your help man. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are the "A Enable" and "B Enable" jumper pins shorted as the picture below?

[image]

Comment: No sir, they arent shorted. Also, I removed the 5v enable jumper as per recommendation i've seen in the net when supplying the motor driver with voltages above 12 volts.

Comment: You did right on disconnecting the 5V jumper pin "5V Enable". But, as i see, in order to make the motors spin, you must short these 2 pins (A, B Enable). Someone, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I read in the net, (source: http://tronixstuff.com/2014/11/25/tutorial-l298n-dual-motor-controller-modules-and-arduino/), that the jumpers are to be removed except when using stepper motors as load. I have to remove the jumpers so that i could connect the enA and enB to the arduino. it would be the arduino which would give/supply voltage to those two pins using the "digitalWrite"/"analogWrite" function.

Comment: These pins, as i see, enable the motors. Try shorting each with a jumper. As i see on the link, the guy who posted the tutorial had his A,B pins shorted with a jumper. Why don't you try shorting them?